# Combining columns for each row in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to combine two columns: Column 1 + Column 2 and that for each row individually. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. How do i solve this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'Nameid': [1, 2, 3, 1], 'Name': ['Michael', 'Max', 'Susan', 'Michael'], 'Project': ['S455', 'G874', 'B7445', 'Z874']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
display(df.head(10))
df['Dataframe']='df'
```

[image]

```
d2 = {'Nameid': [4, 2, 5, 1], 'Name': ['Petrova', 'Michael', 'Mike', 'Gandalf'], 'Project': ['Z845', 'Q985', 'P512', 'Y541']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
display(df2.head(10))
df2['Dataframe']='df2'
```

[image]

---

What I tried

```
df_merged = pd.concat([df,df2])
df_merged.head(10)
```

[image]

```
df3 = pd.concat([df,df2])
df3['unique_string'] = df['Nameid'].astype(str) + df['Dataframe'].astype(str) 


df3.head(10)
```

[image]

As you can see, he didn't combine every row. He probably only has the first combined with all of them. How can I combine the two columns row by row?

What I want

[image]

Comment: I think typo - `df3['unique_string'] = df3['Nameid'].astype(str) + df3['Dataframe'].astype(str) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply `concat` strings like this:

**You don't need to do `df['Dataframe'].astype(str)`**

```
In [363]: df_merged['unique_string'] = df_merged.Nameid.astype(str) + df_merged.Dataframe

In [365]: df_merged
Out[365]: 
   Nameid     Name Project Dataframe unique_string
0       1  Michael    S455        df           1df
1       2      Max    G874        df           2df
2       3    Susan   B7445        df           3df
3       1  Michael    Z874        df           1df
0       4  Petrova    Z845       df2          4df2
1       2  Michael    Q985       df2          2df2
2       5     Mike    P512       df2          5df2
3       1  Gandalf    Y541       df2          1df2
```

Comment: @Mayank Porwal thank you very much! It worked! Why I have to call this `df_merged.Nameid` ?

Comment: `df_merged.Nameid` is the `Named` column from `df_merged`. you can also call it like `df_merged['Nameid']`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using the `df3` assign back to `df3` ,also do `reset_index`

```
df3 = df3.reset_index()
df3['unique_string'] = df3['Nameid'].astype(str) + df3['Dataframe'].astype(str)
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my 
lack of concentration! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `df3` instead `df`, also `ignore_index=True` for default index is added:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df,df2], ignore_index=True)
df3['unique_string'] = df3['Nameid'].astype(str) + df3['Dataframe']
print (df3)
   Nameid     Name Project Dataframe unique_string
0       1  Michael    S455        df           1df
1       2      Max    G874        df           2df
2       3    Susan   B7445        df           3df
3       1  Michael    Z874        df           1df
4       4  Petrova    Z845       df2          4df2
5       2  Michael    Q985       df2          2df2
6       5     Mike    P512       df2          5df2
7       1  Gandalf    Y541       df2          1df2
```